# AWS: can i use all the 18 free tier eligible products at the same time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Based on the information posted in aws website at http://aws.amazon.com, AWS Free Tier is designed to enable you to get hands-on experience with AWS at no charge for 12 months after you sign up.
After creating your AWS account you can use `any of the 18 products` and services, listed below, for free within certain usage limits. I have create one `EC2` instance and i also want to create Orace `RDS` at the same time.

The thing that is confusing me is , whether i could use only one of the 18 products or one from each product at the same time?

Comment: You might ask Amazon support and then come back here and answer your question. Also, a programmers forum is not a good place for a question related to a Vendors seriices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a thread at aws forum https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=169578 and get important information i thing i should share.

> You can use any of the 18 products and services offered under free tier at the same time. For example, you can use EC2, RDS and S3 at the same time as long as you stay within the usage limits. `Note that if you don't use the full benefits provided by the free tier in a given month, they don't roll over to the next month. To maximize your benefit from the free tier, be sure to spend time with AWS each month, investigating the services that you're curious about`.
>
> If you exceed the usage limits of the free tier, use a service that does not provide free tier benefits, or continue to use AWS after you are no longer eligible for the free tier, you are charged at the standard billing rates for your AWS usage.

Answer (score 4):

You can use all of them, each has its own free-tier limits.